# how to parse json data from a string instead of a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to parse a json data which is in NSString how can i do this

```
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
    NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:data];
   for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {
        id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
        SearchCode *theObject =[[SearchCode alloc] init];
        [theObject setCodeValue:[dict objectForKey:@"CodeValue"]];
        [theObject setCodeDescription:[dict objectForKey:@"CodeAddedDate"]];    
        [theObject setCodeAddedDate:[dict objectForKey:@"CodeAddedDate"]];
        [theObject setCodeID:[dict objectForKey:@"CodeID"]];
        [theObject setUpdateDateTime:[dict objectForKey:@"UpdateDateTime"]];

        [cptArray addObject:theObject];
        [theObject release];
        theObject=nil;

       }
```

DataController Class

```
@interface DataController : NSObject {

}
+ (id)staticVersion;
- (NSMutableArray *) startParsing:(NSString *)theURLString;
@end


#import "DataController.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation DataController
DataController *theInstance;


+(id)staticVersion
{
    if(!theInstance){
    theInstance = [[DataController alloc] init];
}
return theInstance;
}

- (NSMutableArray *) startParsing:(NSString *)theURLString {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theURLString]];
NSString *fileContent= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];  
NSArray *items = (NSArray *) data ;  
return items; 
 }

 @end
```

Comment: http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/

Comment: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html

Comment: @Anand i have also followed these ways you can see my code i want instead of url the data should parse from string var as given

Comment: Just have a look at this-------http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077007/how-to-parse-a-json-string-in-iphone-objective-c

Comment: i have seen they also given same link of url to get data and parse it as i have done

Comment: I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858814/nsjsonserialization-from-nsstring

Answer (score 1):

[This Post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/05/classes-for-fetching-and-parsing-xml-or.html) contains classes to parse JSON, XML etc. I have been using these.

Answer (score 1):

In the new sdk you do not have to use external classes to parse your JSon you can use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) witch is Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

To parse a json String using this class you will need to convert your NSString to NSData, you can do that with:

```
NSData *data = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

After that you can use the method to convert the data to json:

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Your returned type will depend, because it will be like your json, if your json is an array, it will be an array, if is a dictionary, it will be a dictionary, and so on.
From apple documentation:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary. All objects are
>   instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull. All
>   dictionary keys are instances of NSString. Numbers are not NaN or
>   infinity.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, you will need to convert it to NSData, like I put on the first line of code, and after that, you will convert this data to NSArray or NSDictionary, like I put in the second line of code.

Comment: Thanks it gives me great help, my data from server is coming in string rather than dictionary or array, so it was difficult to access the key values, but with this code i converted the string into data then json and then dictionary and so on.